# Plone test-runner errors

Tags: plone

Can anyone explain please what could be wrong:

I have a fresh Plone 4.1.4 installation via buildout and a fresh out-of-box Plone site created (no work is done on the site). After running ./bin/test --all testsuite (just out of curiosity) it gives lots of the following errors:

```
Mik@S-linux:/Plone414/PLONE414/zinstance> 
./bin/test --all

./bin/test:239: DeprecationWarning: zope.testing.testrunner is deprecated in favour of zope.testrunner. /Plone414/PLONE414/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.testing-3.9.7-py2.6.egg/zope/testing/testrunner/formatter.py:28: DeprecationWarning: zope.testing.exceptions is deprecated in favour of zope.testrunner.exceptions from zope.testing.exceptions import DocTestFailureException Running Testing.ZopeTestCase.layer.ZopeLite tests: Set up Testing.ZopeTestCase.layer.ZopeLite in 0.071 seconds. Running: 8/44 (18.2%)

Failure in test testDateTime (Products.DocFinderTab.tests.testAnalyse.TestAnalyse) Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Plone414/PLONE414/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 279, in run testMethod() File "/Plone414/PLONE414/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.DocFinderTab-1.0.5-py2.6.egg/Products/DocFinderTab/tests/testAnalyse.py", line 198, in testDateTime  self.assertEqual(self.ob.getdoc('_DateTime').Type(), 'DateTime') File "/Plone414/PLONE414/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 350, in failUnlessEqual (msg or '%r != %r' % (first, second)) AssertionError: 'DateTime instance' != 'DateTime'

Ran 44 tests with 1 failures and 0 errors in 1.376 seconds. Running zope.testing.testrunner.layer.UnitTests tests: Tear down Testing.ZopeTestCase.layer.ZopeLite in 0.000 seconds. Set up zope.testing.testrunner.layer.UnitTests in 0.000 seconds. Running: 2/47 (4.3%)
Failure in test test_search_modules (plone.reload.tests.test_code.TestSearch) Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Plone414/PLONE414/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 279, in run testMethod() File "/Plone414/PLONE414/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.reload-2.0-py2.6.egg/plone/reload/tests/test_code.py", line 33, in test_search_modules self.assertTrue(found) File "/Plone414/PLONE414/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 325, in failUnless if not expr: raise self.failureException, msg AssertionError 5/47 (10.6%)

Error in test test_check_mod_times_change (plone.reload.tests.test_code.TestTimes) Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Plone414/PLONE414/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 279, in run testMethod() File "/Plone414/PLONE414/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.reload-2.0-py2.6.egg/plone/reload/tests/test_code.py", line 82, in test_check_mod_times_change
our_entry = MOD_TIMES[our_package] KeyError: '/Plone414/PLONE414/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.reload-2.0-py2.6.egg/plone/reload/__init__.pyc'

8/47 (17.0%)

Failure in test test_get_mod_times (plone.reload.tests.test_code.TestTimes) Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Plone414/PLONE414/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 279, in run testMethod() File "/Plone414/PLONE414/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.reload-2.0-py2.6.egg/plone/reload/tests/test_code.py", line 70, in test_get_mod_times self.assertTrue(our_package in times) File "/Plone414/PLONE414/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 325, in failUnless if not expr: raise self.failureException, msg AssertionError 10/47 (21.3%)

Error in test test_reload_code_change (plone.reload.tests.test_code.TestTimes) Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Plone414/PLONE414/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 279, in run testMethod() File "/Plone414/PLONE414/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.reload-2.0-py2.6.egg/plone/reload/tests/test_code.py", line 98, in test_reload_code_change our_entry = MOD_TIMES[our_package] KeyError: '/Plone414/PLONE414/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.reload-2.0-py2.6.egg/plone/reload/__init__.pyc'

Ran 47 tests with 2 failures and 2 errors in 0.102 seconds. Tearing down left over layers: Tear down zope.testing.testrunner.layer.UnitTests in 0.000 seconds. Total: 91 tests, 3 failures, 2 errors in 1.682 seconds.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a supported way to run the tests. Some of the tests for the components of Plone change global state and then do not clean up after themselves, causing failures in tests that run later which depended on that state being a certain way. The environment we use to develop Plone, [buildout.coredev](http://github.com/plone/buildout.coredev), uses the plone.recipe.alltests buildout recipe to set up a script that can run all the tests successfully by isolating some packages from others.

This is of course not ideal, but it's a pragmatic solution until someone does the work to find and solve the test isolation problems.